# How to assess maximum number of recursive calls before stack overflows

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Lets take a recursive function, for example factorial. Lets also assume that we have a stack of 1 MB size. Using a pen and paper, how can I estimate the number of recursive calls to the function before the stack overflows? I'm not interested in any particular language but rather in an abstract approach.

There are questions on SO that look similar but most of them are concerned with a specific language, or extending stack size, or estimating it by running specific function, or preventing overflow. I would like to find a mathematical way to estimate it.

I found similar question in an algorithmic challenge but couldn't come up with any reasonable solution.

Any suggestion highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

In response to provided replays if the language truly cannot be taken out of the equation let's assume it's C#. Also, since we are passing simple int or long to the function it's not passed by reference but as a copy. Also, assume a naive implementation, without hashing, without multi-threading, an implementation that as much as possible resembles a mathematical representation of the function:

```
    private static long Factorial(long n)
    {
        if (n < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Negative numbers not supported");
        }

        switch (n)
        {
            case 0:
                return 1;
            case 1:
                return 1;
            default:
                return n * Factorial(n - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: stack_size / function_frame_size (i.e. the amount of space on the stack corresponding to each function call).  The latter is course language/implementation-dependent.

Comment: I added some edits to clarify questions that came up in comments and replays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It highly depends on the implementation of the function. How much memory does the function use, before calling itself again. When it recurses 100 times, you will also have 100 function scopes in memory, including the function arguments and variables. It also reserves 100 places on the stack to store the return values.

I don't think the language can easily be taken out of the equation, because you need to know exactly how the stack is used. For examples are objects passed by reference? Or are the objects copy as a new instance on the stack?