# Why does this factorial program work?

Tags: c#, recursion, factorial

This is a factorial program shown in the tutorialpoints C# tutorial, I understand the basic concept of recursion, but i'm not sure why it works in this context. The program is this:

```
public int factorial(int num)
{
    /* local variable declaration */
    int result;
    if (num == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        result = factorial(num - 1) * num;
        return result;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NumberManipulator n = new NumberManipulator();
    //calling the factorial method
    Console.WriteLine("Factorial of 6 is : {0}", n.factorial(6));
    Console.WriteLine("Factorial of 7 is : {0}", n.factorial(7));
    Console.WriteLine("Factorial of 8 is : {0}", n.factorial(8));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Trace it's operation on a sheet of paper.

Comment: You would be amazed what you can understand with a pencil, paper, and a little bit of effort. I mean, really there only like 5 lines you have to look at.

Comment: @Takendarkk I actually did that before I posted here, I was not able to figure out why it worked and I figured someone here would be able to help. But sure be glib instead of taking a few minutes to explain a supposedly easy concept.

Comment: As a side note, recursive functions are more suited to functional programming languages that can avoid stack overflow - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006049/how-to-assess-maximum-number-of-recursive-calls-before-stack-overflows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During your recursion you will decrease the value of num by 1 and when the recursion stop because num == 1 then you will return your recursion and mutltiply each values.

```
factorial(5)   
      -> factorial(4) * 5
           -> factorial(3) * 4
                    -> factorial(2) * 3
                             -> factorial(1)
```

at the end if will do : 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120;